# how to create a class from a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, class

I'd like to create some classes in a loop, I give the name of the class in a variable.
I get an error:
**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in ...
How can I do this?

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('routes.xml');

$routes = $xml->Route;

    for($i =0; $i<count($routes); $i++){

        $uri = $routes[$i]->attributes()->uri;
        $name = $routes[$i]->attributes()->name;


        Route::set($uri, function(){
            $name::CreateView();
        });

    }
?>
```

**File XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Routes>
    <Route name="Home" uri="" controller="Home"/>
    <Route name="AboutMe" uri="o-mnie" controller="AboutMe"/>
    <Route name="Interests" uri="o-mnie/zainteresowania" controller="AboutMe" method="interests"/>
    <Route name="Contact" uri="kontakt" controller="Contact"/>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Yes, I have class Home with a static function CreateView, i would just like to use a variable as the class name and i don't know how

Comment: @CodeCaster, personally I find the best way of learning out how to write your own framework is trial and error.  Quite commonly I understand why things are done more down to the errors and problems I face rather than just writing code that works.  Although I think this general point is outside the scope of answering any question like this - IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch attributes from a SimpleXML document, the return value is a SimpleXMLElement.

So if you were to `var_dump($name)` you would get something like...

```
class SimpleXMLElement#8 (1) {
  public ${0} =>
  string(4) "Home"
}
```

This cast is done usually implicitly when a method knows it needs a string, so but in this case it doesn't. The easiest way is to cast this to a string...

```
$name = (string)$routes[$i]->attributes()->name;
```

Your second problem is a general scope error ( a good explanation is at [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and))...

```
Route::set($uri, function() use ($name) {
        $name::CreateView();
    });
```

Comment: I used your method but I keep getting the same error

Comment: @karamba, which line is the error on?  Is the error still exactly the same or is it that the class doesn't exist?

Comment: I also got another "Undefined variable" error with "$ name :: CreateView ();" so I get these two errors as if $ name was not passed

Comment: @karamba, see updated code.